# A question in integration by parts in $E(t)=\frac{1}{2} \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} (u_t^2+c^2|\Delta u|^2) dx$

Tags: calculus, partial-differential-equations

I am trying to understand an example which includes using integration by parts. The question is to prove that $E(t)$ is constant.

Suppose you have the PDE

$u_{tt}=c^2 \Delta$, where $x\in \mathbb{R^n}, \ t>0$

With initial conditions

$u(x,0)=g(x)$

$u_t(x,0)=h(x)$

Suppose $u(x,t)$ is a solution, let us define its energy at $t$ by

$$E(t)=\frac{1}{2} \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} (u_t^2+c^2|\Delta u|^2) dx$$

Prove that the energy is conserved.

We have $\frac{dE}{dt}= \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} (u_t u_{tt}+c^2 \sum_{i=1}^n u_{x_i} u_{x_it}) dx$

Integration by parts then yields $\frac{dE}{dt}= \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} u_t (u_{tt}-c^2 \Delta u) dx=0$

What I did not understand is how the integration by parts was done. Can someone please show me exactly how it was calculated?

I know that integration by parts is $\int u \ dv=uv-\int v du$. And I am assuming that they let $u=u_{x_i}$ and $dv=u_{x_it} dx$. But I still didn’t get what they got.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming $u$ decays to 0 rapidly at infinity,  \begin{align*} 
 \int_{\mathbb R^n} \sum_{i=1}^nu_{x_i}u_{x_i t}\, dx &= \sum_{i=1}^n\int_{\mathbb R^n} u_{x_i}u_{ tx_i}\, dx \\
&=-\sum_{i=1}^n \int_{\mathbb R^n} u_{x_ix_i}u_{ t}\, dx \\
&=- \int_{\mathbb R^n} (\Delta u) u_{ t}\, dx.
\end{align*} The second inequality comes form integration by parts. There is no boundary term because of the decay assumption.

---

To be more explicit, if $v,w$ decay rapidly to 0 at infinity, the integration by parts formula over $\mathbb R^n$ is $$\int_{\mathbb R^n  } vw_{x_i} \, dx = -\int_{\mathbb R^n  } v_{x_i}w \, dx  . $$ Above we had $v=u_{x_i}$ and $w=u_t$.

Comment: It is much clearer now, thanks! If the integration was over $[0,1]$ instead of $\mathbb{R}^n$, would the formula still hold?

Comment: If that were the case you would need to impose boundary conditions on $u$ (zero Dirichlet boundary conditions do it) which force the boundary integral to vanish. But then yes